# Bring data of DataFrame back to local node for further actions (count / show) in spark/scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark 1.6 in Scala.

I know it's some of the ideas behind the Spark Framework. But I couldn't answer it to myself by reading different tutorials.. (maybe the wrong ones).

I joined two DataFrames to a new one (**nDF**). Now I know, it's not yet proceeded, as long I say show, first or count.

But since I want to do exactly this, I want to inspect nDF in different ways:

```
nDF.show
nDF.count
nDF.filter()
```

..and so on, it would each time take a long time, since the original DataFrames are big. Couldn't I bring/copy the data to this new one. So I could solve these new actions as quick as on the original sets? (First I thought it's 'collect', but it only returns a Array, no DataFrame)

Comment: Why not  `cache`?

Comment: Thanks @zero323 that I was searching for, I just couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic scenario. When you join 2 Dataframes spark doesn't do any operation as it evaluates lazily when an action called on the resulting dataframe . Action mean show, count, print etc.

Now when show, count is being called on **nDF**, spark is evaluating the resultant dataframe every time i.e once when you called show, then when count is being called and so on. This means internally it is performing map/reduce every time an action is called on the resultant dataframe.

Spark doesn't cache the resulting dataframe in memory unless it is hinted to do so by doing df.cache / df.persist.

So when you do

```
val nDF = a.join(b).persist
```

And then call the count/show it will evaluate the nDF once and store the resulting dataframe in memory. Hence subsequent actions will be faster.

However the fist evaluation might be little slower also you need to using little more executor memory.

Answer (score 0):

If the memory available to you is good with respect to the size of your dataset, what you're probably looking for is `df.cache()`. If the size of your dataset is too much, consider using `df.persist()` as it allows different levels of persistence.

Hope this is what you're looking for. Cheers